# How to compute $\int_0^1 (1-y)^{(n-1)}(e^{zy}-1)dy$

Tags: calculus

How do I compute $\int_0^1 (1-y)^{(n-1)}(e^{zy}-1)dy$?

I have tried integration by parts and got the following:

$(e^{zy}-1)\frac{(1-y)^n}{n}\mid_0^1-\int_0^1\frac{(1-y)^{n}}{n}ze^{zy}$

How can I get a definitive expression to evaluate on the [0,1] interval?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It turns out that I missed an item in my last equation, it should be zIn=(n−1)In−1−1zIn=(n−1)In−1−1, which will be difficult to solve now. I guess that's why Jan has a Gamma function in his result (+1), I could see that. So I'll delete mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, we can apply linearity and expanding:

$$\mathscr{I}_{\space\text{n}}\left(\text{z}\right):=\int_0^1\left(\exp\left(\text{y}\cdot\text{z}\right)-1\right)\cdot\left(1-\text{y}\right)^{\text{n}-1}\space\text{d}\text{y}=$$
$$-\left(-1\right)^\text{n}\cdot\left\{\int_0^1\exp\left(\text{y}\cdot\text{z}\right)\cdot\left(\text{y}-1\right)^{\text{n}-1}\space\text{d}\text{y}-\int_0^1\left(\text{y}-1\right)^{\text{n}-1}\space\text{d}\text{y}\right\}\tag1$$

Now, use:

- Substitute $\text{u}=\left(\text{y}-1\right)^\text{n}$ and assume $\text{n}\ne0$:
  $$\int_0^1\exp\left(\text{y}\cdot\text{z}\right)\cdot\left(\text{y}-1\right)^{\text{n}-1}\space\text{d}\text{y}=\frac{\exp\left(\text{z}\right)}{\text{n}}\int_{\left(-1\right)^\text{n}}^0\exp\left(\text{z}\cdot\text{u}^\frac{1}{\text{n}}\right)\space\text{d}\text{u}\tag2$$
- Substitute $\text{v}=\text{u}\cdot\text{z}^\frac{1}{\text{n}}$:
  $$\int_{\left(-1\right)^\text{n}}^0\exp\left(\text{z}\cdot\text{u}^\frac{1}{\text{n}}\right)\space\text{d}\text{u}=\frac{1}{\text{z}^\text{n}}\int_{\left(-1\right)^\text{n}\cdot\text{z}^\frac{1}{\text{n}}}^0\exp\left(\text{v}^\frac{1}{\text{n}}\right)\space\text{d}\text{v}=\frac{1}{\text{z}^\text{n}}\cdot\left[-\frac{\text{n}\cdot\Gamma\left(\text{n},-\text{v}^\frac{1}{\text{n}}\right)}{\left(-1\right)^\text{n}}\right]_{\left(-1\right)^\text{n}\cdot\text{z}^\frac{1}{\text{n}}}^0\tag3$$
- Substitute $\text{p}=\text{y}-1$:
  $$\int_0^1\left(\text{y}-1\right)^{\text{n}-1}\space\text{d}\text{y}=\int_{-1}^0\text{p}^{\text{n}-1}\space\text{d}\text{p}=\left[\frac{\text{p}^\text{n}}{\text{n}}\right]_{-1}^0=\frac{0^\text{n}}{\text{n}}-\frac{\left(-1\right)^\text{n}}{\text{n}}=-\frac{\left(-1\right)^\text{n}}{\text{n}}\tag4$$

Comment: Sorry but I do not know the gamma function. So I cannot understand fom there henceforth. Anyway thanks!